# Wrapping a function call into a closure when using goroutines

Tags: go, closures, goroutine

Wrapping a function call into a closure leads to an unexpected behaviour when using goroutines.

Consider the following example:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var workerNum = 5
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func block() {
    dur := 300 * time.Millisecond
    //time.Sleep()
    select {
    case <- time.After(dur): {}
    }
}

func startWorker(worker int) {
    for i:=0; i < 3; i++{
        log.Printf("Worker %d woke up! \n", worker)
        block()
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    for i:=0; i < workerNum; i++ {
        //go func() { startWorker(i) }()
        go startWorker(i)
    }

    wg.Add(workerNum)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Test it here: http://play.golang.org/p/nMlnTkbwVf

One can see that wrapping `startWorker(i)` into `func() { startWorker(i) }()` results in calling only the 5-th worker.

It looks like there is something wrong in the way how closures capture variables from the outer scope. Why is this happening? Do closures use pass-by-reference way for passing outer variables instead of pass-by-value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how closures in all languages work, if you want to do it that way, you have to isolate the variable.

```
go func(i int) { startWorker(i) }(i)
```